# The type automorphisms over $D[X]$, where $D$ is an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

> If $D$ is an integral domain, then show that every automorphism $f$ of $D[X]$ which is identity on $D$ is of the form $f(X)=cX+d$, where $c$ is a unit of $D$.

It is easy to show that a function of this form is a ring automorphism and is uniquely determined by the conditions. But why each automorphism is of this form?
This is Exercise 14 on page 167 in Hungerford's *Algebra*.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, make your question clear. In this case what do you mean by "$f$ is identity on $D$"? Are you saying $f$ is the identity transformation, where $f(X)=X$ for all $X$? If not, what do you mean?

Comment: I believe the OP means that $f$ fixes any element of $D$.

Comment: Let $p=f(X)$. Then $f(Q)=Q\circ p$. But in integral domains $\deg(Q\circ p)=\deg Q\cdot \deg p$, so imposing surjectivity yields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g = \sum_{k=0}^N b_k X^k$ be the polynomial for which $f(g) = X,$ where $b_N \ne 0.$ Then $$\sum_{k=0}^M b_k f(X)^k = X.$$
Since $D$ is an integral domain, $b_N$ will not cancel with any of the nonzero coefficients of $f$, so you will not be able to solve this equation unless $f(X)$ (and $g$) both have degree $1$.